# Búsqueda en Django admin por un campo de una tabla externa demasiado lenta

Tags: django, postgresql, django-models, django-forms, django-admin

Tengo dos modelos (tablas) en Django:

```py
class Perro(models.Model):
    nombre = models.CharField(max_length=30, db_index=True)

class Ladrido(models.Model):
    fecha_ladrido = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.utcnow)
    mascota = models.ForeignKey('Perro',
                            related_name='ladrido_perro',
                            on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

En el form de admin, quiero buscar todos los ladridos de los perros que se llamen de una forma. Por ejemplo, todos los ladridos de los perros que se llamen 'Max' sacaría los ladridos de los perros que se llamen Max, Maximilian, etc.
Tengo esto:

```py
class LadridoAdmin(BaseAdmin, BaseActions):
    paginator = MyPaginator
    list_display = ('id', 'fecha_ladrido', 'mascota')
    search_fields = ('mascota__nombre', )
```

En la base de datos, hay millones de ladridos.
El problema es que en el formulario de admin, cada búsqueda tarda mucho tiempo, aunque el perro que busque tenga sólo 1000 ladridos:
**Tiempos de carga (aprox):**

> Carga de tabla :   Instantáneo
>   Resultados de búsqueda: 15 segundos

Para mejorar esto, ordeno primero por el campo de búsqueda:

```py
class LadridoAdmin(BaseAdmin, BaseActions):
    paginator = MyPaginator
    list_display = ('id', 'fecha_ladrido', 'mascota')
    search_fields = ('mascota__nombre', )
    ordering = ('mascota__nombre',)
```

Y ahora tenemos estos **tiempos de carga (aprox):**

> Carga de tabla :   15 segundos
>   Resultados de búsqueda: Instantáneo

¿Cómo puedo mejorar ambos tiempos simultáneamente?

### EDIT : Usando la función get_search_results

Basándome en la [documentación oficial de Django admin](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.get_search_results), la función *get_search_results* puede sobreescribirse para mejorar el tiempo de búsqueda. He probado esto:

```py
class LadridoAdmin(BaseAdmin, BaseActions, admin.ModelAdmin):
    paginator = MyPaginator
    list_display = ('id', 'fecha_ladrido', 'mascota')
    search_fields = ('mascota__nombre', )

    def get_search_results(self, request, queryset, search_term):
        queryset, use_distinct = super(LadridoAdmin, self).get_search_results(request, queryset, search_term)
        # Hacer un set con las mascotas que tienen ese nombre
        mascotas = Perro.objects.filter(nombre__contains=search_term)
        # Coger solo los ladridos con mascota en el set
        queryset |= self.model.objects.filter(mascota__in=mascotas)
        return queryset, use_distinct
```

Pero estoy haciendo algo mal, porque ahora tenemos estos **tiempos de carga (aprox):**

> Carga de tabla :   Instantáneo
>   Resultados de búsqueda: 15 segundos

Answer (score 1):

El problema es que por cada ladrido que buscas, Django tiene que hacer otro query adicional para obtener la relación con su perro correspondiente. Lo que puedes intentar para mejorar la eficiencia del query es usar [`select_related`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/querysets/#select-related). Para esto puedes sobreescribir el método [`get_queryset`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.get_queryset) del `ModelAdmin`:

```
class LadridoAdmin(BaseAdmin, BaseActions, admin.ModelAdmin):
    paginator = MyPaginator
    list_display = ('id', 'fecha_ladrido', 'mascota')
    search_fields = ('mascota__nombre', )

    def get_queryset(self, request):
        query = super(LadridoAdmin, self).get_queryset(request)
        return query.select_related('mascota')
```

Basicamente, lo que hace `select_related` es un JOIN con la otra tabla, conviertiéndolo en un solo query más complejo pero, a la vez, más eficiente.

Es probable que se reduzca bastante el tiempo, me comentas cómo te va.

Comment: La idea es buena, pero, tarda lo mismo

Comment: @MouTio puede que tu problema sea otro. Usa django debug toolbar para descartar que el problema sea el query.